# Powershell search text file for match and add carriage return at the end of the line

Tags: arrays, powershell, append

I am attempting to parse a text file and match set of characters and then add a carriage return at the end of that line to add some spacing. I have tried a number of different ways to do this but haven't been successful. Code sample below results in matching and returning only the lines with the match and doesn't add the carriage line.

```
[string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\abc.txt" 
$Return = $arrayFromFile -match 'ghijk' -split "`r"
$Return | Out-File "C:\abc.txt"
```

**Results:**

- ghij
- ghmno
- ghabc

What I want to do is below. Find the results "gh" and add a carriage return at the end of that line while keeping all of the content in the text file.

**From:**

- abcdefmno
- abcdefpqr
- ghij
- abcdef
- ghmno
- abcdef
- abcdef
- ghabc
- mnop

**To:**

- abcdefmno
- abcdefpqr
- ghij

- abcdef
- ghmno

- abcdef
- abcdef
- ghabc

- mnop

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in a single pipeline:

```bsh
Get-Content -Path "C:\abc.txt" | foreach {
   $_
   if ($_ -like "gh*") {
       "" # additional empty line
   }
} | Out-File "C:\abc.txt"
```

Instead of inserting any line breaks or carriage returns, outputting an empty line (empty string) is enough. The line breaks will be automatically handled by `Out-File`.

Instead of `-like "gh*"` (to satisfy the requirement of your example), you can of course do `-match <your regex>` or whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply marsze!  That makes much more sense and worked with the -match <regex>.

Comment: @kprober Thank you. I recommend you also check out Doug Maurer's answer. It's a very elegant alternative to do it, and might even be a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

We combine all the steps in a switch statement with the `-Regex` and `-File` parameters. It will read the file line by line, we match against letters gh and on those matching lines add a blank line to the output. All this is captured in `$return` and then we use `Set-Content` to write it back out.

```
$file = 'c:\abc.txt'

$return = switch -Regex -File $file {
    gh {$_; ''}
    default {$_}
}

$return | Set-Content $file -Encoding UTF8
```

Note `Out-File` can be problematic with encodings thus I changed it to `Set-Content`

Comment: Nice use of switch. I was thinking about that too. I recommend adding an empty line (`$_; ""`) instead, and let powershell handle the correct line endings.

Comment: I thought about [environment]::newline as well. I’ll update it, thanks for the suggestion.